# How do I optimize this UNION query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this test schema:

```
CREATE TABLE A
(
  ID INT PRIMARY KEY,
  A VARCHAR(1),
  B VARCHAR(3),
  C VARCHAR(3),
  BID INT,
  DATE DATETIME2(7)
)

INSERT INTO A values
(1, NULL, 'AAA', 'XXX', 1, '2018-04-04'),
(2, NULL, 'BBB', 'YYY', 2, '2018-05-05'),
(3, NULL, 'CCC', 'ZZZ', 2, '2018-06-06')

CREATE TABLE B
(
  ID INT PRIMARY KEY,
  X VARCHAR(1),
  Y VARCHAR(1),
  Z VARCHAR(1)
)

INSERT INTO B values
(1, 'A', 'A', 'A'),
(2, 'B', 'B', 'B'),
(3, 'C', 'C', 'C'),
(4, 'D', 'D', 'D'),
(5, 'E', 'E', 'E')

CREATE TABLE C
(
  ID INT PRIMARY KEY,
  NAME VARCHAR(12)
)

INSERT INTO C values
(1, 'Mary'),
(2, 'John'),
(3, 'Peter')

CREATE TABLE D
(
  ID INT PRIMARY KEY,
  CID INT,
  R VARCHAR(3),
  S VARCHAR(3)
)

INSERT INTO D values
(1, 1, 'AAA', 'ABC'),
(2, 2, 'BBB', 'ZZZ'),
(3, 1, 'FOO', 'ZZZ'),
(4, 3, 'BAR', 'YYY')
```

And I have this query:

```
WITH T1 AS
(
    SELECT A.ID, A.A, A.B, A.C, B.X, B.Y, B.Z
    FROM A
    LEFT JOIN B
    ON A.BID = B.ID
    WHERE A.DATE BETWEEN '2018-01-01' AND '2018-12-31'
)

(
    SELECT T1.ID, T1.A, T1.B AS VALUE, T1.X, T1.Y, T1.Z, T2.NAME
    FROM T1
    LEFT JOIN
    (
        SELECT C.NAME, D.R
        FROM C
        INNER JOIN D
        ON C.ID = D.CID
    ) AS T2
    ON T1.B = T2.R
)
UNION ALL
(
    SELECT T1.ID, T1.A, T1.C AS VALUE, T1.X, T1.Y, T1.Z, T2.NAME
    FROM T1
    LEFT JOIN
    (
        SELECT C.NAME, D.S
        FROM C
        INNER JOIN D
        ON C.ID = D.CID
    ) AS T2
    ON T1.C = T2.S
)
```

The fiddle is [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/4c5ca/1).

The execution plan can be found in the fiddle.

Looking at current execution plan, there are two trees branching out from a concatenation. Both trees are almost identical. This means that the query inside `T1` has been executed twice due to the `UNION ALL`. Is there any way I can rewrite this, probably replacing the `UNION ALL` with a `JOIN`?

P.S. Edited question with test schema and fiddle.

Comment: Please post the plan https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/

Comment: please post the complete query

Comment: @Squirrel Updated with test schema and fiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got better plan using the following:

```
;WITH T1 AS
(
    SELECT A.ID, A.A, A.B, A.C, B.X, B.Y, B.Z
    FROM A
    LEFT JOIN B ON A.BID = B.ID
    WHERE A.DATE BETWEEN '2018-01-01' AND '2018-12-31'
)
SELECT T1.ID, T1.A, IIF(v.N=1,T1.B,T1.C) AS VALUE, T1.X, T1.Y, T1.Z, C.NAME
FROM T1
CROSS JOIN (VALUES (1),(2)) v(N) -- or (SELECT 1 N UNION ALL SELECT 2) v
LEFT JOIN D ON ((T1.B = D.R AND v.N=1) OR (T1.C = D.S AND v.N=2))
LEFT JOIN C ON C.ID = D.CID
```

You also can rewrite it without CTE (the same plan but looks shorter):

```
SELECT A.ID, A.A, IIF(v.N=1,A.B,A.C) AS VALUE, B.X, B.Y, B.Z, C.NAME
FROM A
LEFT JOIN B ON A.BID = B.ID
CROSS JOIN (VALUES (1),(2)) v(N) -- or (SELECT 1 N UNION ALL SELECT 2) v
LEFT JOIN D ON ((A.B = D.R AND v.N=1) OR (A.C = D.S AND v.N=2))
LEFT JOIN C ON C.ID = D.CID
WHERE A.DATE BETWEEN '2018-01-01' AND '2018-12-31'
```

Comment: Thanks, this indeed does seem to be faster (overall CPU time decreases by about 30-40%) when I replicate this idea over to my production table/query. The execution plan also no longer has the repeated parts. Going to keep the question open for a little longer to see if anyone else has a better optimization, though.

Answer (score -1):

```
WITH T1 AS
(
    SELECT A.ID, A.A, A.B, A.C, B.X, B.Y, B.Z
    FROM A
    LEFT JOIN B
    ON A.BID = B.ID
    WHERE A.DATE BETWEEN '2018-01-01' AND '2018-12-31'
)

(
    SELECT T1.ID, T1.A, T1.B AS VALUE, T1.X, T1.Y, T1.Z, C.NAME
    FROM T1
    Left JOIN D ON 
    T1.C = D.R
    LEFT JOIN C ON 
    C.ID = D.CID

)
UNION ALL
(
    SELECT T1.ID, T1.A, T1.C AS VALUE, T1.X, T1.Y, T1.Z, C.NAME  
    FROM T1
    Left JOIN D ON 
    T1.C = D.S
    LEFT JOIN C ON
```

Comment: I don't see how this really significantly changes the execution plan.

Comment: It ignores the nested loops